# Confirm popup not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a problem as the confirm popup is not showing, when i use my delete button. The deleting works fine, i just dont get the "are you sure" popup first.

I have tried different variantions of this code, without any luck. I think i have the confirm part correct, but perhaps not. What am i missing here?

```
<%= link_to t('common.delete'), car_path(@current_work_context, car), :method => :delete, :confirm => t('common.are_you_sure'), :class => "btn btn-danger btn-xs" if car.deletable? %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change `:confirm => t('common.are_you_sure')` to `data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }`, or an old version: `:data => { :confirm => 'Are you sure?' }`

And what about your `application.js`? Does it includes `jquery` like this:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
```

?

Comment: data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } works.. But i want to use the t-function for translations.. How do i insert it in the brackets ?

Comment: data: {confirm: t('common.are_you_sure')}